# how to define the return value type of app.mount()

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

how to define the return value type of `app.mount()` ？

I have a component and want to create [Multiple application instances](https://vuejs.org//guide/essentials/application.html#multiple-application-instances), but when I use the return value of the `mount()` to modify the variables associated with the component, ts prompts me that

```
Property 'content' does not exist on type 'ComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, false, ComponentOptionsBase<any, any, any, any, any, any, any, {}>'
```

here is my component, and expose content

```
// myComponent
<template>
hello
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const content = ref('')
defineExpose({ content })
</script>
```

mount component to dom in `main.ts`

```js
// main.ts
import myComponent from './myComponent.vue'
const tooltipInstance = createApp(myComponent).mount('#v-tooltip')
tooltipInstance.content = 'xxx'
```

At this time, ts reports an error for `tooltipInstance.conent`

```
Property 'content' does not exist on type 'ComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, false, ComponentOptionsBase<any, any, any, any, any, any, any, any, any, {}>>'.ts(2339)
```

Is there any way to get the type of component and apply it to the return value of  `app.mount()`

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-mount):

```
interface App {
  mount(rootContainer: Element | string): ComponentPublicInstance
}
```

As you can see the mount method returns a ComponentPublicInstance and furthermore,

> For each app instance, mount() can only be called once.

So I do not think you can do what you desire in the mount method.

Comment: `ComponentPublicInstance` is a generics, I don't know how to pass parameters.
As for `For each app instance, mount () can only be called once`,  there is no need to worry about that. `myComponent` in the demo only used to mount on `#v-tooltip`

Answer (score 0):

> Although the editor will give an error prompt, the value of content can be obtained. For example, I set it to 'xxx', which can be printed on the console, which means that the value can be obtained. But before that, you need to set a container with the id of v-tooltip in index.html under the project root directory to mount your instance

```html
// index.html
<div id="v-tooltip"></div>
```

```
// myComponent
<template>
hello
</template>
    
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const content = ref('Hello World')
defineExpose({ content })
</script>
```

```
// main.ts
const app = createApp(myComponent);
const temp = app.mount('v-tooltip')
console.log(temp.content) // The editor will still prompt errors here, 
// but in fact, you have exposed this attribute through the defineExpose method. 
// Expected: output 'Hello World', actual: output 'Hello World'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, although ts reports an error, it can operate normally

Comment: I do have two mounted dom in index.html  `<div id="app"></div><div id="v-tooltip"></div>`